# Is it possible to invoke a dynamic object in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a situation where I have an object of type "dynamic" that is invokable. I'm trying to implement a function that will invoke the object dynamically at runtime with a set of arguments. It is easy enough to invoke it if I know the number of arguments at compile time:

```
Object StaticInvoke(dynamic func, Object[] args) {
    // arguments are explicitly unwrapped and bound to the invokation
    // requiring that we know the number at compile time
    return func(args[0], args[1], ...); 
}
```

But, this doesn't accomplish what I want because the args array could be of variable length. I can't figure out a way to support an arbitrary number of arguments. The closest I've come up with is something like:

```
static Object Invoke(dynamic func, Object[] args)
{

    // not sure what to put here
    switch(args.Length)
    {
        case 0:
            return func();
        case 1:
            return func(args[0]);
        case 2:
            return func(args[0], args[1]);
        ...
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Which would limit the number of arguments I could possibly pass. I guess I could live with this limitation, but it feels like what I'm trying to do should be possible.

I'm basically trying to implement the javascript "apply" function in C#. Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Why would users of your code call `Invoke` instead of just calling `func(...)` directly?

Comment: I suspect there is an built in way to do what you are trying to do by using reflection, but I'm no expert in that area. Instead, I will mention that if you want to use a variable number of arguments in C#, you should look at the `params` keyword. My disclaimer being that I don't think you actually want `params`, you want to invoke a method using reflection.

Comment: @M.Babcock: the "invoke" that I'm trying to create is implementing an interface method  so that we can work with new dynamic invocations the same way that we work with "legacy" invocations in old script engines that we use.

Comment: Your next question will probably be: why not try to dynamically bind to the legacy interface instead and treat everything as dynamic. Well, because we have a large code base and that change would be more disruptive that we want right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opensource apache licensed ImpromptuInterface (on nuget) has a static method [Impromptu.Invoke](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic_Impromptu.Invoke%28object_target,_params_object%5B%5D_args%29) that does this. You can look at the implementation, while it handles an arbitrary number of arguments, it also does work that you probably don't need such as providing a mechanism to dynamically described named arguments and invoke them.

Your switch case idea might actually be the way to go depending on your usage as it should be both simple and fast.

With your switch case, with N being the largest number of arguments you support, the C# compiler will create N+1 callsites that it just statically knows where they are. Impromptu will being calling the dlr apis, just like the compiler, but it will be [storing the callsite in a hashtable](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/ImpromptuInterface/src/Optimization/InvokeHelper-Regular.cs#140) which will add look up time (not bad though).

The dlr api's also require a delegate the has a signature that matches the number or arguments your are calling, again the compiler will make sure you statically have N+1 delegates, while Impromptu will use the 17 built-in Func<> in a switch case and then [start emiting new delegates as needed](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/ImpromptuInterface/src/Optimization/InvokeHelper.cs#274), it's a one time heavy cost to generate and then adds more hashtable look ups for subsequent calls.

Comment: The impromptu stuff looks a little overkill for what I need. I guess the switch will be good enough. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is not an answer - keeping it here to let others know that it is unlikely what @Mark looking for.

For regular objects you would use [`MethodBase.InvokeMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx):

```
 MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic");
 object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[]{100});
```

Comment: No; he's trying use `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`.